# What gases are needed for humans to breathe?

Tags: physiology, respiration

I will be beginning a science project about sustaining life on space stations. I already know that pure oxygen is harmful for humans but would $O_2$ + $CO_2$ be enough for humans to breathe in or do humans need other gases as well?

Comment: For a start, in addition to the International Space Station (ISS), also look at gas mixtures used in [scuba diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scuba_diving#Gas_mixtures) and [breathing gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathing_gas).

Comment: This is a good question, as understanding the minimum requirements of human respiration has many applications beyond that of a space station, extending to future biospheres both on Earth (eg under the ocean) and beyond.

Comment: Yes that what my science project is about, it's about sustaining life on Mars so I just needed to know what gasses are required for human respiration respiration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not look at the existing space station as an example.  The International Space Station (ISS), a starting article is ["Breathing easy on the space station"](http://science1.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2000/ast13nov_1/) (NASA), while this article does not discuss the amounts of various chemicals, it looks at the process about how the chemical balance is maintained - an important point related to your question is that carbon dioxide is filtered away.

The second article ["Breathing on the Space Station"](http://www.e-missions.net/ssa/CH4-breathingonthespacestation.htm) (e-missions), discusses the actual percentages of each component.  It states that the chemical composition of the space station air is ideally similar to Earth's atmosphere.  With 78% nitrogen, 21% oxygen and 1% water vapour on the space station (Argon is in the Earth's atmosphere, but appears to be unnecessary on the space station).

I hope this helps.